# Continuity of maximum of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is from Abbott's Analysis. It is:

Observe that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then
$$
\max\{a,b\}=\frac{1}{2}[(a+b)+|a-b|].
$$
Show that if $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$ are continuous functions, then
$$
g(x)=\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots,f_n(x)\}
$$
is a continuous function.

The base case, when $n=1$ follows because $f_1(x)$ is assumed continuous. Do we need to look at $n=2$ (because when do we incorporate the $\max\{a,b\}$ bit?) And for the induction step, I don't know how to show that $f_{n+1}$ is continuous if I assume the first $n$ are continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denoted $g_n(x)=\max\{f_1(x),...,f_n(x)\}$instead of $g(x)$,by induction $g_n$ has been continuous, and so $g_{n+1}(x)=\max\{g_n(x),f_{n+1}(x)\}$ we can get that $g_{n+1}(x)$ is continuous.

The symbol you use here might be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: how can you just say $f_{n+1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Oh, just use max argument. ok!

Comment: Eh... the continuity of $f_{n+1}$ must be the assumption

Comment: What? How can we assumte the $f_{n+1}$ case? I thought we have to show that and we can do that by looking at $g_{n+1}$, which is continuous.

Comment: If we add a new non-continuous function to the case, their maximum can be also non-continuous, isn't that. Eh

Answer (score 4):

Two observations. It is not hard to show that

1. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous, so is $$\frac 12 \left( \, f_1 + f_2 + |f_1 - f_2| \,\right)$$
2. $\max\{ f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n \} = \max \{ \max\{ f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_{n-1} \}, f_n \}$

Given those, can you now proceed?